# Data Menu not available in Microsoft Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-office

I would like to **present data in *Microsoft Visio Diagrams***.

On my own workstation I can add data sources like an SQL server and bind data to shapes in the diagram.

When I save such a document to disk as a *Viso Drawing (.vsd)* and send this document to another person, **all data is preserved, but refreshing this data is impossible**. (data becomes static) So I suppose the "other person" is missing something in the document I send him.

Besides that:

- I am using **Microsoft Visio Premium** (together with a full setup sharepoint developer environment)
- He is using **Microsoft Visio 2010 Standard**. His menu also lacks the availability of the Data tab in the menu.

[image: the data menu that is available on my workstation]

I am trying to determine if:

1. The difference in versions also **eliminates the use of "live" data**.
2. The document has to be saved in a **different format** in the first place (not as .vsd)
3. An **alternative solution** for this problem if both above are not
   possible.